# Software for design 3D graph

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, graph

I'm looking for a software for designing 3D graph (graph with x,y,z axis).

I found [OmniGraphSketcher](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraphsketcher/) but it seems that it allows me to design only 2D graph.

I don't want to use Matlab because my graph will not be a "mathematical" graph. It would be a graph with text and not dots or line or numbers.

I have to do something like the picture below but in a professional way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following Software for visualizing X,Y,Z Data as a 3D Scatter and 3D Surface graph:

- [IGOR Pro](http://www.wavemetrics.com/products/igorpro/creatinggraphs/3dandvolume.htm)
- [QtiPlot](http://soft.proindependent.com/plot-gallery.html)
- [R](http://www.r-project.org/)
- [Graphing Calculator](http://www.pacifict.com/Products.html#ThreeDimensions)

These are for the most part scientific tools, so don't expect any friendly UI. There are some other tools for *nix and Windows, but the you have to use Wine, Crossover or some VM to use it.

There is also '[ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery_3dscatter.html)' - a Script for PHP, ASP, JSP etc. for usage directly in HTML.

But I am still wondering: if all you want to do is put in some Text on a chart with 3 Axis, wouldn't it be easier for you to draw the graph by hand?

You could [Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html), [InkScape](http://inkscape.org/), [Sketch](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) or [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/)

Comment: Thanks, however I'm afraid that no one of the proposed SW are fine with my request. Because I don't have to make a mathematical graph. Please, see the example picture in the question.

Comment: At the end I did it with OmniGraffle...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built-in [Grapher app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) in /Application/Utilities ?

Comment: Thanks! I tried but I wasn't able to design what I want. See the edited question.